# Why can't TypeScript modules implement or adhere to an interface? Can I get around this?

Tags: typescript

It seems like it would be very useful in TypeScript to require that a module implement an interface.  Is there any particular reason why they've chosen to not implement this ability?

I can't think of any reason why it would be undesirable to allow a module implement an interface, but if it is, then is there any other way to require a module provide a certain set of properties / methods?

Comment: Put a class in the module that implements the interface, you are only a dot away from having what you want.

Comment: That would be undesirable for me but I did think about that before asking this question.  If I did that, I'd have an extra, unnecessary definition and I'd also have to differentiate between the definition of the type and the assignment of the instance.

Comment: Related discussion on the official TypeScript repository: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/420

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force a compile error if a module doesn't adhere to an interface like this (technically non-zero runtime overhead, but unlikely to actually matter):

```
interface foo {
    bar(): number;
}

module mod {
    export function bar(): number {
        return 0;
    }
}
var mod_is_foo: foo = mod; // errors if you change 'number' to 'string' above
```

As for why can't you say `module mod implements foo`? [All features start at minus 100](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericgu/minus-100-points).

Edit to add -- here are some other (somewhat wacky) things you could write in lieu of the `var` statement above if you wanted to avoid creating a new top-level var:

```
<foo>mod; // Shortest, probably fastest?
<foo>undefined === mod; // Clearest non-var version?
```

Comment: Thanks for the direct feedback Ryan, you and the team are doing great things.  I'll start getting involved on typescripts area on codeplex.

Comment: I was actually able to use this work around, but in a slightly different manner.  I was building components that were to be used in a mediator pattern and I was "registering" all of the components with the core system.  When I was registering them, I was passing the actual module into a method and I just made that method only accept an interface that contained everything that I wanted the modules to provide.  That way it ensured those modules adhered to the interface.  Thanks again Ryan!

Comment: As of TypeScript 9.1 you can use the 'typeof' keyword to solve this problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/08/06/announcing-0-9-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ryan is actually on the Typescript team so his answer is pretty much final. But I personally think its nice that it doesn't provide the syntax you seek.

The reason is that a module is more like an instance instead of being something that can be instantiated (e.g. a class). In this way it is closer to a var than a class.

So reason becomes that its similar to why you would write:

```
var x:foo;
```

instead of

```
var x implements foo;
```

modules behave the same in that you can do

```
var y:foo = mod;
```

as Ryan pointed out already.

Also check this out:

```
interface foo {
    bar(): number;
}

module mod {
    export function bar(): number {
        return 0;
    }
}

var x: foo; 
x = mod;

// Still a bit whacky but allowed as module is a type as well as an instance
var y:mod;
y = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your module within a TypeScript class with a well-defined interface. A small downside is that you need to instantiate the class before using it.

**./Foo.ts**

```js
export default interface Foo {
    bar(): number;
}
```

**./FooImpl.ts**

```js
import Foo from "./Foo";

export default class FooImpl implements Foo {
    bar(): number {
        return 13;
    }
}
```

**./Main.ts**

```js
import Foo from "./Foo";
import FooImpl from "./FooImpl";

const foo: Foo = new FooImpl();

export default function main(): number {
    return foo.bar();
}
```

**./FooMock.ts**

```js
import Foo from "./Foo";

export default class FooMock implements Foo {
    bar(): number {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

**./Main.test.ts**

```js
import main from "./Main";

jest.mock('./FooImpl', () => {
    return jest.requireActual('./FooMock').default;
});

describe('Main', () => {
    it('should return 42 for the mock Foo implementation', () => {
        expect(main()).toBe(42);
    });
});
```